# If line from file equals user input

Tags: python

So I have this code:

```
f=open('spells.txt')
input = raw_input("What spells?")
for line in f:
        if line == input:
                print line
f.close()
```

I am trying to figure out why it wont read the title of a spell I put in. I know the read works because I can print out a certain number of lines. What is there that I am not understanding about file input versus user input. I feel like there is a hidden \n somewhere, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think `line` contain `'\n'` while raw_input doesn't

Comment: To be more specific, `line.rstrip('\n')`

Comment: You're overwriting the built-in function [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). That's not an error, but it might be a bad idea.

Comment: @Matthias I didnt even think of that, Ive change my variable.

Comment: Under normal circumstances noone will use `input` with Python 2, but if your code runs on Python 3 there is only `input` (with the functionality of `raw_input` from Python 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines in files contains new line character `'\n'` in the end, try this:

```
if line.rstrip() == input.strip():
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated code:

```
f=open('spells.txt')
userInput = raw_input("What spell?")
for line in f:
        if line.rstrip('\n') == userInput:
                print line
f.close()
```

It still produces the same result, which is nothing shows up and it goes back to the command line. I will try the other strips, but I thought I would post this here as an update.

Comment: try to add '\r' to rstrip: rstrip('\r\n') or just call it without any args

Comment: I tried both with '\r\n' and without any args. Neither returned anything, I am starting to wonder if there is an issue with my python install. I tried just doing print line.rstrip() without the if statement and it works. So something isnt working correctly in the comparison and I havent figured it out yet.